# date foreach array

Tags: php

Why doesn't this work, its suppose to pick from the arrayed dates which the current date falls between. so for example if the date is `16-01-30` the date chosen would be `16-02-14` Thankyou for helping me.

```
    <?
    $date = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28');
    $currentdate = date('y-m-d');
    echo $currentdate;
    ?>
    <form>
    <select>
    <?php
    foreach ($date as $i => $d) {
        if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($date)-1 || $currentdate < $date[$i+1])) {
            $selected = "selected";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
        echo "<option $selected>$month/$day/$year</option>";
    }
    ?>
    </select>
    </form>
```

Comment: You need to use strtotime to compare the date. Or use DateTime class for the variable

Comment: and if current date is 16-02-25 than chose 16-02-28 ?? or is just a typo error?? $date or $dates?

Comment: @devpro what do you mean `and if current date is 16-02-25 than chose 16-02-2` is there something that could go wrong with this code on a specific date you can see?

Comment: @LewisTyler: if current date is 16-02-12 than what value to be selected from array????

Comment: well , u need to select last latest date? m i right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your answer

```
$dates = array('16-01-14','16-01-28','16-02-14','16-02-28');
    $currentdate = date('y-m-d');
    echo $currentdate;
    ?>
    <form>
    <select>
    <?php
    foreach ($dates as $i => $d) {
        if ($currentdate >= $d && ($i == count($dates)-1 || $currentdate < $dates[$i+1])) {
            $selected = "selected";
        } else {
            $selected = "";
        }
        list($year, $month, $day) = explode('-', $d);
        echo "<option $selected>$month/$day/$year</option>";
    }
```

Comment: You are using `$date` instead of `$dates`.